# New Windows Azure Web Site with Umbraco fails during install

Tags: azure, umbraco

Has anyone successfully created a Windows Azure Web Site with Umbraco?

I followed the steps to create a new Umbraco site and when I first run the site I'm given the standard install page. When I get to the Create User portion it fails with a NullReferenceException.

Note: I'm not installing Umbraco to a web role. This is the new Windows Azure Web Site preview.

Answer (score 1):

The information is not enough to pin point the error however i have worked a few issues in which exact same error occurred when Plugins were part of Umbraco configuration or there was issue connecting SQL Database. During your Umbraco configuration you may have configured the SQL Database connection so can you verify that same connection string does work from your local machine (i believe you may have to set the firewall correctly)

Also have you collected the site log (FTP to your websites and look for log folder) to see if there is any more info about this issue. You also have one more option to report your issue directly at [Windows Azure Websites forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazurewebsitespreview/threads) and someone from websites team will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure find the apps sections and install Umbraco from apps and then it will work fine